# [NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, int

Alright, I'm having the following common problem

`[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

but this time I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's the declaration in `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *tempHours = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
        [tempHours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+1)]];
    }
    self.hours = tempHours; // 'hours' is a synthesized NSArray property of the ViewController
    [tempHours release];

  // two more similar array declarations here

}
```

Here's the code method of the UIPickerView where stuff breaks (e.g., the `if` statement)

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *stringIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row #%d", row];

    if(component == 0) {
        return stringIndex = [self.hours objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    // more code for other components (of the same form) here

    return stringIndex;
}
```

I think I need my NSArray of NSNumber objects to be type-casted as strings. How do I do that  properly with that statement:

`stringIndex = [self.hours objectAtIndex:row];`

Thanks!

Comment: N.B. You should not release `tempHours` in `viewDidLoad`. You do not own it because you did not create it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.hours objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Comment: I had the same error, but this did not work for me. stringValue did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9586079/956397

Answer (score 8):

You are returning an `NSNumber` as that is what is held in `self.hours`. As `NSString` is the expected return value you should create a string via:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.hours objectAtIndex:row]];
```

or reevaluate your intent. Did you actually want to store indices in this way, or did you want to store `NSStrings`?

Comment: I wanted to store numbers for hours. For minutes, I nee to store strings, since I'm prepending 0s for the numbers 1-9. I'll have to then read out the values later on back into numbers when I apply the `didSelect:` method

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is having this problem and specifically returning an index of a row, then you can always convert the NSNumber to a stringValue by doing the following:

```
NSString *code = [[[JSONResponse objectForKey:@"meta"] objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue];
```

Placing a `stringValue` at the end of the method will convert anything to a string, you can also use `intValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Comment `[tempHours release];`//it is autoreleased object. You didn't use and with alloc or copy or new:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *tempHours = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
        [tempHours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+1)]];
    }

    self.hours = tempHours; // 'hours' is a synthesized NSArray property of the ViewController

    // [tempHours release];
}
```

more over u have added NSNumber to array
so
convert to string value:

```
stringIndex =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.hours objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Comment: Nope, that still doesn't work. Throws this error `-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: so u have added some string to hours array .so use like above stringwithformat

Comment: Yup, I appreciate that, too! Thanks!

Comment: @Vijay let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1959/discussion-between-lazyrussian-and-vijay)