# -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString] error

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm getting this crash, but, in my code I am using a string. I've been working on this one piece of code for 2 hours now and I just can't see what I'm missing! Any ideas?

```
 NSString *codeR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[object objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue]];

    if([codeR isEqualToString:@"200"])
```

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181cf0'

I would be very grateful input, this is confusing the hell out of me!

Thanks.

Comment: a little bit more code would be nice

Comment: There must be some code between these two lines. Otherwise it wouldn't crash.

Comment: Yes, please post here ALL lines between the two code lines you posted above.

Comment: There isn't any code between the two. Honest. Above these lines is a JSONParser grabbing some returnData from a request to a server.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Get rid of silly redundancy, see what happens.

```
NSString *codeR = [[object objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue];
// mysterious missing code
if ([coreR isEqualToString:@"200"]) // etc
```

Also, are you sure the error is raised from the `if` statement you posted? It could be coming from elsewhere.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. It was definitely coming from the if, changing the statement/breakpoints testing all pointed to that. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you very much @psoft . Help me solve my JSON parsing issue as well :)

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *codeR = [[object objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue];

if ([codeR isEqualToString:@"200"])
{
// Do stuff...
}
```